# Build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

#"Problem in Port Audio installation through cmd."#

**I have tried all the possible ways from the community answers mentioned.But Still i am getting the same error..**

```
#this is the code
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import PortAudio

r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  print('Speak Anything:')
  audio = r.listen(source)

  try:
      text=r.recognize_google(audio)
      print('you said: {}'.format(text))
  except:
      print('sorry could not recognize voice')
```

> ERROR:Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback
> SystemExit:-1.

To solve the above issue I have tried to install `pyaudio` through a GUI based app which went fine but when I tried to execute the program, I got to know I need to install a wheel module through the cmd where I used

```
pip install C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

then it gave the following error:
> ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

For the past 5 hours I have been working on it. Any Suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem.

First change your code to this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  print('Speak Anything:')
  audio = r.listen(source)

  try:
      text=r.recognize_google(audio)
      print('you said: {}'.format(text))
  except:
      print('sorry could not recognize voice')
```

i.e. remove `import pyaudio` and `import portaudi`o

then in the Command Prompt run:

```
pip install pipwin
```

And then:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```